# datetype single text change the value

Tags: symfony

I have a `DateType` `input` in my `formBuilder`. In my form, when I put `12/12/1500`, it changes the date to `12/12/1901`. I use it with widget single`_`text, format `dd/MM/yyyy` and input `datetime`

I have removed all the validations constraint on the field, so it has to come from the `Type`

How can I change this unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#input

"If timestamp is used, DateType is limited to dates between Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT and Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT on 32bit systems. This is due to a limitation in PHP itself."

Try changing the 'input' option for the your date field.

Comment: I am using the datetime input